# Visual Studio Code (Mac OS) rename symbol doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, refactoring, rename

When I right click and try to rename a variable name in Microsoft Visual Studio Code on Mac OS Mojave, it prompts for the new name, I hit enter and nothing happens.

I have Python extension and Latex extension installed.

Usually there are no errors, no nothing.

Sometimes, there's a little box that pops up saying "No Result. No Result".

The python interpreter I selected was a Conda install.

I ensured rope, and pylint were installed.

Expected behaviour:
right click > rename symbol > type new name > enter > all instances of variable renamed.

Observed behaviour
right click > rename symbol > type new name > enter > variable has same name everywhere, including spot of renaming.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14363

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It turns out the solution was simple, but frustrating. To do refactoring in VS Code (at least for python) you need to be in a workspace.

I solved the problem by first closing the open folder I was in:

File > Close Folder.

then navigating to a sub folder of .py file I was editing, and opening it. In my case it was

1. Click the little document icon in the upper left of screen
2. In the welcome screen, choose "open folder"
3. navigate to my desktop folder (where my .py file is)

Now refactoring works as expected

Click on file icon in upper left of screen > in the welcome screen

Comment: One more variation: Although I was already in a Workspace, it was untitled. Once I saved it with a name, refactoring worked.

Comment: There is this key combination which is called 'rename symbol', but that's not working even when in a workspace. I'm using intelliSense by Microsoft for C/C++

Answer (score 6):

I use Pylance with a workspace and had the same issue. For me the solution was to restart the language server (from the Command Palette). I find it faster than closing and opening the folder.

`Ctrl+Shift+P` > Python: Restart Language Server

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a folder did not solve the issue for me. I switched to a new language server called [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) and everything works fine now.

Comment: Run into same issue, mine was using Jedi python language server and it is the default setting. It appears that is the cause of renaming issue. After googling for awhile, finally decided to try a different language server, and Pylance worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that if you use Pylance (Pyright) and have a `pyrightconfig.json` or a `[tool.pyright]` section in `pyproject.toml`, this can cause refactoring to fail.

In my case I had not put the localtion of the script into the `include` array in `pyproject.toml` so it was giving the "No results" error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to reset the Python Language Server setting:

```
"python.languageServer": "Default",
```