# VS Code Elixir F2 "rename symbol" not working

Tags: elixir, visual-studio-code

I'm using [ElixirLS: Elixir support and debugger `JakeBecker.elixir-ls`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakeBecker.elixir-ls) and `editor.formatOnType` is working just fine.

Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a variable doesn't work.  There is no Output from `ElixirLS`.

What I've tried:

- Using the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) - nothing useful when typing "rename".
- Having only the one extension ElixirLS active
- Right-clicking on a symbol to rename only lists the syntax-unaware "Change All Occurences".
- [Saving a new workspace as suggested for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55017235/5353461)

How do I easily rename variables in Elixir with VS Code?

Comment: It should work. I've checked it in my machine. You should recheck your extensions. Maybe it has some conflicts between them.

Comment: Search the Keyboard Shortcuts (Code -> Prefs -> Keyboard Shortcuts) for "Rename Symbol". Mine shows "Shift+F6", but this more or less does a find/replace with a live cursor scoped to the *entire* file, with no awareness of what is a var name vs. map key. I.e. still useless and not what you need.

Comment: @Minh-Khang are you sure you're using the same extension myself, given what Everett and the answer from eddy147 below?

Comment: Sure. Try to right click to variable instead of `F2`

Answer (score 2):

ElixirLS currently does not support this feature.
I have created a feature Request for it: https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls/issues/436